# How to I copy an existing Xamarin Studio iTouch project to a different folder?

Tags: xamarin

I have an existing Xamarin Studio iTouch iOS project named DoctorRegistration2012. I want to copy this project and call it DoctorRegistration2013. Then I want to open the copied project in Xamarin Studio and continue develop. How can this be done quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the directory your origin project lives in, name the new directory whatever you want, and then if you open the .sln solution file in the new directory in Xamarin Studio you should be fine.

You can then rename the solution by right mouse clicking on the solution in the Solution Explorer and select "Rename."

Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding something!